# Fetching private GitLab repo via HTTP

Tags: http, gitlab, private

My plan is to use deploy tokens to access private repos (hosted GitLab).

This one works fine:

```
 git clone https://my-gitlab-deploy-token-user:my-gitlab-deploy-token-pass@gitlab.com/username/projectname.git
```

Accessing archive.tgz fails with authentication error:

```
curl https://my-gitlab-deploy-token-user:my-gitlab-deploy-token-pass@gitlab.com/username/projectname/repository/archive.tar.gz?ref=master
```

Anyone has an idea why the token authentication works fine using HTTP endpoint for the Git client but fails fetching the archive tarball directly?

Comment: There is a possibly related [issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/60900) on GitLab.

Answer (score 1):

The [*deploy token*](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/) only allow to clone repository and read docker registry.

Whereas, the [*Personal Access Tokens*](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) allow to authenticate "against Git over HTTP or SSH". 
Note, they are only limited to the following: API,RSS,Registry. There is a note about about this limitation due to an "Improper Enforcement of Token Scope" on the [gitlab blog](https://about.gitlab.com/2018/11/28/security-release-gitlab-11-dot-5-dot-1-released/).